# Err invalid arg value

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This error shows up whenever I try to npm start my react app.

(node:12372) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Starting the development server...

node:internal/fs/utils:676
throw err;
^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'path' must be a string or Uint8Array without null bytes. Received 'C:\React.js CodeWithHarry CWH 29.3.23\#2 Creating our first react app using create-react-app  Complete React Course in Hindi ...
at readdir (node:fs:1358:10)
at go$readdir (C:\React.js CodeWithHarry CWH 29.3.23#2 Creating our first react app using create-react-app  Complete React Course in Hindi #2 30.3.23\textutils\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:206:16)
at Object.readdir (C:\React.js CodeWithHarry CWH 29.3.23#2 Creating our first react app using create-react-app  Complete React Course in Hindi #2 30.3.23\textutils\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:211:12)
at CacheBackend.provide (C:\React.js CodeWithHarry CWH 29.3.23#2 Creating our first react app using create-react-app  Complete React Course in Hindi #2 30.3.23\textutils\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:193:18)
at CaseSensitivePathsPlugin.getFilenamesInDir (C:\React.js CodeWithHarry CWH 29.3.23#2 Creating our first react app using create-react-app  Complete React Course in Hindi #2 30.3.23\textutils\node_modules\case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin\index.js:59:6)
at CaseSensitivePathsPlugin.fileExistsWithCase (C:\React.js CodeWithHarry CWH 29.3.23#2 Creating our first react app using create-react-app  Complete React Course in Hindi #2 30.3.23\textutils\node_modules\case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin\index.js:101:8)
at checkFile (C:\React.js CodeWithHarry CWH 29.3.23#2 Creating our first react app using create-react-app  Complete React Course in Hindi #2 30.3.23\textutils\node_modules\case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin\index.js:162:10)
at C:\React.js CodeWithHarry CWH 29.3.23#2 Creating our first react app using create-react-app  Complete React Course in Hindi #2 30.3.23\textutils\node_modules\case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin\index.js:196:7
at CaseSensitivePathsPlugin.primeCache (C:\React.js CodeWithHarry CWH 29.3.23#2 Creating our first react app using create-react-app  Complete React Course in Hindi #2 30.3.23\textutils\node_modules\case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin\index.js:132:5)
at Object.onAfterResolve [as fn] (C:\React.js CodeWithHarry CWH 29.3.23#2 Creating our first react app using create-react-app  Complete React Course in Hindi #2 30.3.23\textutils\node_modules\case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin\index.js:191:10) {
code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE'
}
PS C:\React.js CodeWithHarry CWH 29.3.23#2 Creating our first react app using create-react-app  Complete React Course in Hindi #2 30.3.23\textutils>

I expected my react app to start and load on local host as usual.

Comment: can you please post your code?

Comment: I havent started coding, I just did basic create react app and wanted to load it from src/app.js to my local host

Comment: import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.